# How to check if a Date object or Calendar object is a valid date (real date)?

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-8, java-time

`SimpleDateFormat` class's method:

```
public void setLenient(boolean lenient)
```

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient. With lenient parsing, the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not precisely match this object's format. With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

or the `Calendar` class's method:

```
public void setLenient(boolean lenient)
```

> Specifies whether or not date/time interpretation is to be lenient. With lenient interpretation, a date such as "February 942, 1996" will be treated as being equivalent to the 941st day after February 1, 1996. With strict (non-lenient) interpretation, such dates will cause an exception to be thrown. The default is lenient.

checks for the conformity of the format or rolls the date.

I would like to confirm if the date with `MM-DD-YYYY` (02-31-2016) should return invalid as 31day in feb is not a real date so should 04-31-1980 also return invalid.

Would not like to use Joda time API from Java 8 however any suggestion on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: getActualMaximum and getActualMinimum might help in the Calendar class.

Comment: To correct a misunderstanding: Joda-Time is NOT in Java-8 but an independent and very different library. The new java.time-package is only inspired by Joda-Time and has been implemented from the scratch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Java Time API, this can be done using the [`STRICT`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#STRICT) `ResolverStyle`:

> Style to resolve dates and times strictly.
>
> Using strict resolution will ensure that all parsed values are within the outer range of valid values for the field. Individual fields may be further processed for strictness.
>
> For example, resolving year-month and day-of-month in the ISO calendar system using strict mode will ensure that the day-of-month is valid for the year-month, rejecting invalid values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy")
                                                   .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
    LocalDate.parse("02-31-2016", formatter);
}
```

This code will throw a `DateTimeParseException` since it is not a valid date.

By default, a formatter has the [`SMART`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/ResolverStyle.html#SMART) `ResolverStyle`:

> By default, a formatter has the SMART resolver style.

but you can change this by calling [`withResolverStyle(resolverStyle)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withResolverStyle-java.time.format.ResolverStyle-) on the formatter instance.

Comment: Do we have anything similar in Java7 API

Comment: @Shekar163 Before Java 8, you'd either have to rely on Calendar or use Joda Time.

Comment: did try with Calendar however it is not as accurate compared to Joda time however I have a limitation wont be able to use Joda time.

Comment: If no solution exists other than Joda Time API or Java8 i will be forced to use Java8

Comment: well it is I have to consider lot of other parameters before going for an upgrade to java8 ;) which you do understand

Comment: thanks for the answer your solution fits my requirements .... even though I am forced to upgrade to java8

Answer (score 1):

```
final static String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-MM-yyyy";

public static boolean isDateValid(String date) 
{
        try {
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
            df.setLenient(false);
            df.parse(date);
            return true;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried the solution you have suggested thanks however it is not what i am looking for

Comment: @Shekar163 The answer is okay because modifying the pattern to "MM-dd-yyyy" will yield false for your input "02-31-2016" (the same for your other example "04-31-1980"). So I don't see what is your real problem. Or is your pattern wrong??? I hope you have not used "MM-DD-YYYY".

Comment: @Meno i am looking for joda Time API alternative or Java8 API alternative in java7 above solution is OK but ain't what i am looking for I would want you to give it a good thought if the solution was that good was there a point in having Joda Time API or Java8 embedding Joda Time ?

Comment: @Shekar163 As said in my other comment, Java-8 does NOT contain Joda-Time. Both libraries are very different despite of the use of some equal class names. But maybe you are looking for [ThreetenBP](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threetenbp) which is the backport of the new time library in Java-8 for platforms of version 6 or 7. Doing so you can apply the same code like in Java-8 (after having changed the import-statements) with some few exceptions.